# How to select select multiple columns in data source on mac? in tableau on mac

Tags: tableau-api

When I load excel file I would like to pivot some columns.How can select many of them at the same time? I use on Mac shift+CMD and select each of them separately but I know could somehow select first and last column and the middle ones would be also selected, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to select the first and last column and then have the middle columns be selected. To do that, select the first column and as you select the last column press the shift key (for a Mac). 
Hope this helps!